# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given open:

Tags: laravel

I have facebook login which uses socialite library. The error in the question occurs when the callback occurs.

Here is my "USER" model

```
    <?php



namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable  

{
     //use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

   public function posts()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }



}
```

The Socialite logins are handled by SocialAuthController and what i understood from the error is , **auth()->login($user);** , null is passed to the login("NULL"). Here is the code of SocialAuthController. What's the mistake i have made here and how to fix this. thanks in advance

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Socialite;
use App\SocialAccountService;

class SocialAuthController extends Controller 
{

public function redirect($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

public function callback(SocialAccountService $service , $provider)
    {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver($provider));

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->to('/home');
    }

}
```

The below is the handling service that will try to register user or log in if account already exists. 
Here is the code of **SocialAccountService.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider;

class SocialAccountService
{
    public function createOrGetUser(Provider $provider)
    {

        $providerUser = $provider->user();
        $providerName = class_basename($provider); 

        $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider($providerName)
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => $providerName
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {

                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;

        }

    }
}
```

This will try to find provider's account in the system and if it is not present it will create new user. This method will also try to associate social account with the email address in case that user already has an account.

Comment: What is *SocialAccountService* and what *createOrGetUser* does?

Comment: The requested details with the code are updated in the question. Kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that *createOrGetUser()* returns *NULL* because the *SocialAccount* does not have a user. So what could do is change the *if* condition in that method to check if the `$account` has a user:

```
public function createOrGetUser(Provider $provider)
{
    ...
    if ( $account && property_exists($account, 'user') && $account->user ) {
        return $account->user;
    } else {
    ...
```